# Как исправить, то что парсинг сайта возвращает пустую строку?

Tags: php, парсер

пытаюсь спарсить сайт fl.ru

```
$options = array('http'=>array('method'=>"GET", 'header'=>"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8\r\n"."User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.50 Safari/537.36 OPR/65.0.3467.16 (Edition beta)\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$link = 'https://www.fl.ru/projects/4550152/rerayting-teksta.html';
$string = file_get_contents($link, false, $context); 
echo $string;
```

в итоге получаю пустую переменную, при том что другие сайты все норм работают

Comment: Есть достаточно большая вероятность того что ip забанили, т.к. у меня приведённый код отработал нормально и выдал желаемую страницу. Так же советую вместо `file_get_contents` использовать [`curl`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/curl.examples-basic.php)

Comment: не подскажете на каком хостинге вы запускали мой код? не на всех срабатывает

Comment: Локально из консоли) Но только что на timeweb попробовал и сработало

Comment: хм, у меня timeweb  не хочет, даже при смене ip

спасибо большое за ответы)